# How to redirect all URLs except one using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this URL that needs to be closed: 
`www.xxx.com/shops` 
Therefore, I need to redirect all URLs such as `www.xxx.com/shops/xxx` to `www.xxx.com/shops/information/1`, excluding just one specific URL, which is `www.xxx.com/shops/information/1` itself.

Usually, the code below would be fine;

```
get '/shops/',           to: redirect('www.xxx.com/shops/information/1')
get '/shops/*path'       to: redirect('www.xxx.com/shops/information/1')
get '/shops/*path/*path' to: redirect('www.xxx.com/shops/information/1')
```

But this time, since I need to exclude one URL, I can not use `/shops/*path/*path`, and I am assuming that I need to list up all the URLs except for that info page.
Do I need to list up all of the URLs listed on the output of rake routes, or is there a better way to do so?

Example:

```
//partial output of the command 'rake routes'
GET     /shops/login(.:format)
POST    /shops/login(.:format)
DELETE  /shops/logout(.:format)
GET     /shops/password_reset/error(.:format)
GET     /shops/password_reset/finish(.:format)
POST    /shops/password_reset(.:format)
GET     /shops/password_reset/new(.:format)
GET     /shops/password_reset/edit(.:format)

//routes
get '/shops/',                    to: redirect('www.xxx.com/shops/information/1')
get '/shops/login'                to: redirect('www.xxx.com/shops/information/1')
get '/shops/logout'               to: redirect('www.xxx.com/shops/information/1')
get '/shops/password_reset/*path' to: redirect('www.xxx.com/shops/information/1')
get '/shops/password_reset        to: redirect('www.xxx.com/shops/information/1')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes are compiled from top-to-bottom; if you specify in this order:

```
get "/shops/information/1", to: "controllername#action_name
get "/shops/*path", to: redirect...
get "/shops/*path/path", to: redirect...
```

you should be able to reach the information view without any later definitions redirecting in an endless circle.

Since we don't know what your information controller is named, I can't specify exactly what you should send your first result to. Note that if the controller is named `Shops::InformationsController` and the action `show`, you specify it like so: `"shops/informations#show`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When I tried the code above, and put "localhost:3000/shops/information/1", I got an error, saying "The action '1' could not be found for Shops::InformationsController. Do I need to change your first line of code?

Comment: Yes; I've edited my answer to show you but you need to specify which controller and action handles it.

Comment: Oh of course, I need to specify the controller and action! Thank you so much for your kind assistance and comments. You are my saviour. Thank you again for helping me.

Comment: Don't forget to mark answers as accepted with the checkmark, if they solve your issue :)